# Make screen reader ignore "misspelled" words

Tags: html, w3c, screen-readers

Is there an ARIA tag to prevent screen readers (Mac specifically) from saying a word is misspelled? It keeps trying to say a name is misspelled when it isn't.

Comment: No clue if this is possible without a hack, but the first thing that comes to mind for me is wrapping the name inside of a span with aria-hidden set to true and then adding another span (hidden from non-sr users) with the "correct" spelling of the name.

Comment: Bummer...but that's actually a really smart hack. I only need it on one part of the site so this is acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Can you specify whether this is a desktop-only or iOS-only question? (Or does it apply to both?) 2. Have you checked whether this is a screen reader feature that you can disable (on the system where you test your content)?

Comment: I'm seeing this happen on the desktop version of Safari (10.1.2).